# I want to subtract 2 arrays and get a third array which constis of remaining elements of first array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Subtraction of two arrays. 
`a=["AT","IN","UK","US"]` and `b=["UK","ZA"]`. I need result like `a-b = ['"AT","IN","US"]`

I am trying to subtract two arrays in above way, but instead of getting the correct answer I am ending up with `a[]` always. Below is my code:

```js
var prevCountries = ["AT","IN","UK","US"]; 
var sectedCountries= ["UK","ZA"] ;
var deletedCountries =[];
deletedCountries =prevCountries ;

console.log(deletedCountries);
for(i=0;i<prevCountries.length;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=selectedCountries.length;j++)
    {
    if (prevCountries.includes(selectedCountries[j]))   
        {
            var index = deletedCountries.indexOf(sectedCountries[j]);
            if (index > -1) {
                deletedCountries.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u log it after performing the operation ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you can remove the element of `b` array from array `a`.

Make an iteration over array `a` using `filter()`. In every cycle of the iteration check if the element of `a` is not exist in array `b`. `filter()` keep the element if the callback returns true otherwise it remove the current cycle element.

```js
const a = ['AT','IN','UK','US'];
const b = ['UK','ZA'];
const r = a.filter(i => b.indexOf(i) === -1)
console.log(r)
```

Comment: Thanks clean and simple. works like a charm. One question though why is everyone using const instead of var (I am new to programming).

Comment: [Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Answer (score -1):

The trivial solution:

```
prevCountries.filter(x => !sectedCountries.includes(x))
```

or probably a bit faster one, since sets have much more efficient membership test:

```
let sectedSet = new Set(sectedCountries)
prevCountries.filter(x => !sectedSet.has(x))
```